# Accessing defined variable inside <<<HTML in php

Tags: php, constants, heredoc

I'm trying to figure out how to use a defined variable when using `<<<HTML` in php.
This is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
<?php
define('TEST','This is a test');
echo <<<HTML
Defined: {TEST}
HTML;
?>
```

What's the appropriate way of getting the defined "TEST" inside the `<<<HTML` ?

Edit:
I did a small test to check which one of the methods is the fastest.
For my test I used 20 variables inside heredoc. Here is what happened with the different methods (in seconds):
[Accessing defined variable inside <<<HTML in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246839/accessing-defined-variable-inside-html-in-php/5247036#5247036) seems to be the slowest way of doing it - 0.00216103.
[Accessing defined variable inside <<<HTML in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246839/accessing-defined-variable-inside-html-in-php/5246919#5246919) is faster - 0.00073290.
[Accessing defined variable inside <<<HTML in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246839/accessing-defined-variable-inside-html-in-php/5246906#5246906) is even faster - 0.00052595.
[Accessing defined variable inside <<<HTML in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246839/accessing-defined-variable-inside-html-in-php/5246871#5246871) is the fastest - 0.00011110.

Hope this helps somebody else :)

Comment: I wish to upvote this 10x for doing the test, but I can only do one. Thanks for this bro!

Comment: You're welcome! Keep in mind this was a test for older PHP versions back in 2011. Things probably changed since then specially with php >= 7. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not pretty I'm afraid, but ...

```
define('TEST','This is a test');

var $defined = TEST;

echo <<<HTML
Defined: {$defined}
HTML;
```

There isn't, so far as I'm aware at least, a way of using defined values directly in that context, you need to use a variable.

Comment: That's what I though too. I was just curious if there is another way.

Comment: gets the vote - purely because its right. heredoc syntax can only evaluate variables - you'd have to assign a constant to a variable to insert it into your string. Maybe look at an alternative string building technique?

Comment: I use normal variables instead of defined. I was just wondering if things have evaluated to better in php but apparently I'll have to use the variables for a long time :)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a method I found in the notes on the php manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php#100449

It's a little convoluted, but it should work.

```
<?php
define('TEST','This is a test');

$cst = 'cst';
function cst($constant){
    return $constant;
}

echo <<<HTML
Defined: {$cst(TEST)}
HTML;
```

If you have multiple defined CONSTANTS to include, this would be better than manually assigning lots of variables to the value of constants.

Comment: Wow dude ... this code rocks! Never thought you can use functions inside heredoc this way! Thanks for sharing !

Comment: Like I said, it's kind of convoluted.  Credit has to go to the code creator over on the PHP manual.  There are some gems from serious experts over there.

Comment: @Martin:  This is not untrue.  I will not argue.

Comment: @Martin: it's an anonymous function, basically. http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: I see the beauty of anonymous functions, I'd just worry that I accidentally set `$cst` to some other value, e.g. `$cst='runkit_constant_remove'`.

Comment: what about this? define('TEST','This is a ${var}');

Answer (score 4):

You can create a class that acts like an accessor to constants:

```
class DefineAccessor {
    function __get($name) {
        if (defined($name))
            return eval('return ' . $name . ';');
    }
}
```

Create an instance of it to be able to use it in heredoc:

```
$defines = new DefineAccessor;
```

And then use it like this:

```
echo <<<HTML
Defined: $defines->TEST
HTML;
```

Comment: This is a pretty and re-usable solution, kind of a bummer that it's necessary though.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Assign its value into a real variable.

Answer (score 2):

Only this way
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#74744

Comment: As far as I know, a mere link to an external source, which can be unavailable, is not a valid answer on SO. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers (5th element in list)